# Is it okay to write own magic methods?

Tags: python

In my web application I often need to serialize objects as JSON.
Not all objects are JSON-serializable by default so I am using my own `encode_complex` method which is passed to the `simplejson.dumps` as follows: `simplejson.dumps(context, default=self.encode_complex)`

Is it okay to define my own magic method called `__json__(self)` and then use code similar to the following in `encode_complex` method?

```
def encode_complex(self, obj):
    # additional code

    # encode using __json__ method
    try:
        return obj.__json__()
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    # additional code
```

Comment: +1 here, because your question leads me to knowing that name mangling does not occur on methods that also *end in two underscores*. Not that I am going to use it for creating new magic methods.

Comment: An example of a non-standard library dunder is numpy's [`__array__`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.dispatch.html) (among others).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `__double_underscore__` names are reserved for future extensions of the Python language and should not be used for your own code (except for the ones already defined, of course).  Why not simply call the method `json()`?

Here is the relevant section from the [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> `__*__` 
>       System-defined names. These names are defined by the interpreter and its implementation (including the standard library). Current system names are discussed in the Special method names section and elsewhere. More will likely be defined in future versions of Python. Any use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use double underscore due to name mangling http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers -- However in concept what you're doing is fine for your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but private name mangling occurs only for methods which does not end in two or more underscores

Answer (score 0):

As explained in other answers the double underscores shouldn't be used.

If you want to use a method with a name that implies that is to be used only by the internal implementation, then I suggest to use a single leading underscore.

As explained in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> - _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator.  E.g. "from M import *" does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.