# Accessing another module's __all__

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python module and in one of my files I have a fairly complicated expression for `__all__`:

```
# foo.py
__all__ = [ ... ]
```

In the top-level module that I want users to use, I want to expose all of that plus a few others. Do I just explicitly reference `__all__`?

```
# the_module.py
import foo

__all__ = foo.__all__ + [ ... ]
```

or is there some way to do it using:

```
from foo import *

__all__ = ???
```

Comment: Is there some reason to avoid the first form? Have you tried it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'd tried it and it works, it just... looks wrong :)

Comment: Are there things in `the_module.py` that you **don't** want to expose? If not, you don't need `__all__` there at all; you can just include `from foo import *`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Brilliant, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `__all__` is used to **restrict** the names that will be imported from a given module. If there is nothing in `the_module.py` that users *shouldn't* be able to access, then you don't need to define it at all.

`from foo import *` will bring in everything defined in `foo.__main__`, so users that `import the_module` will be able to access all of those names and anything defined in `the_module.py` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can just try it:

```
# foo.py
__all__ = [1,2,3]
```

And then

```
# bar.py
import foo
print foo.__all__
```

output:

```
>>> python bar.py
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or if you want to import just `__all__`directly:

```
# bar.py
from foo import __all__
print __all__
```

output:

```
>>> python bar.py
[1, 2, 3]
```

Python is very friendly to just going for it.

If you want to use the `from module import *` form:

```
# foo.py
__all__ = [1,2,3]
__other_thing__ = [4,5,6]
```

And then

```
# bar.py
from foo import *
print foo.__all__
print foo.__other_thing__
```

output:

```
>>> python bar.py
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Perhaps `foo.__other_thing__` should be changed in this answer, as custom dunders are frowned upon? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302814/is-it-okay-to-write-own-magic-methods